# React only updating in a private browser

Tags: java, reactjs

Hi  i am new to coding and was starting to learn react, i am having an issue when i change the html in the h1 tag the page only updates in private browser. Is there any reason for this or any error i have made. Thanks in advance.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";


export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return <h1>Why does this </h1>;
  }
}

const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
render(<App />, appDiv);
```

Comment: Which browser are you using? Can you describe step wise how you are starting up your react server?

Comment: maybe caching? if you are on chrome, try ctrl+shift+r

Comment: im having the error on both on safari and chrome, for the commands for running i use  django and react i use python3 manage.py runserver and then for react i use npm run dev